# Entry script appears when using CHtml::link

Tags: php, yii

I'm playing with Yii.
I removed Entry script existing in URL using .htaccess and main configuration but It appears again when I use CHtml::links(). How can I fix it?
For example:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
```

UPDATE:
My urlManager config:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        'commentfeed'=>array('comment/feed','urlSuffix'=>'.xml', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,
        '<pid:\d+>/commentfeed'=>array('comment/feed','urlSuffix'=>'.xml', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
        ),
```

My .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set showEntryScript to false in your configuration file.

Please follow framework's official instructions how to do that:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x

Comment: This is the correct answer, but the linked page does not in fact show exactly how to do that. Even if it did, since it's something simple it would be preferable to have the answer here. Including this information in the answer would turn it from useful into great.

Comment: well it doesnt show it in code, but it is stated right on that page

Comment: showEntryScript is false , if it was not false entry scrip appears everywhere but as I mentioned problem is just when I use CHtml::link(). I set my configuration exactly using Yii's documentation. I think a change in using CHtml::link is needed but I don't know what is it.